# How do I change the baud rate for a LoRa device?

Tags: c++, serial-port, baud-rate

I have a LoRa device that uses a default baud rate of 57600 on a USB port of a raspberry pi.  I'd like to experiment with faster serial baud rates.  The instructions to change the baud rate after returning from a device sleep state are as follows from the datasheet:

[image]

I have one major problem in that I don't know what a 'break' code is in serial port communications.  I've tried various things, including the following (where usb_port is the file descriptor of the opened port):

```
ioctl(usb_port, TCSBRK, 0);
```

and

```
std::string msg;
msg="0X00";
write(usb_port, msg.c_str(), msg.size());
```

All with no luck.  Can anyone take a look at this c++ function and tell me where I may be going wrong?

From elsewhere in the documentation, it is indicated that writing "0x55" triggers an auto-baud detection setup when returning from sleep.

Note: radiodevice file descriptor of "/dev/ttyUSBPort1" is a reference to /dev/ttyUSB0 that is set up using a udev serial rule.

```
const char* radiodevice = "/dev/ttyUSBPort1";
int openPort(void) {
    struct termios tty;
    memset(&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
    if ((usb_port = open(radiodevice, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC))>=0) {// | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC
        std::cout << "DEVICE OPENED: " << radiodevice << " handle number: " << usb_port << std::endl;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to open serial radiodevice");
        return -1;
    }
    if(tcgetattr(usb_port, &tty) != 0) {
        printf("Error %i \n", errno);
    }
    cfsetispeed(&tty, B57600);
    cfsetospeed(&tty, B57600);
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;            // Make 8n1
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;           // no flow control
    tty.c_cc[VMIN]   =  0;                  // read doesn't block
    tty.c_cc[VTIME]  =  5;                  // 0.5 seconds read timeout
    tty.c_iflag &= ~ISTRIP;
    tty.c_iflag &= ~INLCR;
    tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNCR;
    tty.c_iflag &= ~ICRNL;
    tty.c_oflag &= OPOST;
    tty.c_lflag &= ICANON;
    tcflush(usb_port,TCIOFLUSH);
    usleep(10000);
    if (tcsetattr(usb_port, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        printf("Error %i\n", errno);
    }

    //FLASH UNIT LED LIGHTS TO CONFIRM INITIAL CONNECTION
    std::string msg="sys set pindig GPIO11 1\r\n";
    write(usb_port, msg.c_str(), msg.size());
    usleep(1000000);
    msg="sys set pindig GPIO11 0\r\n";
    write(usb_port, msg.c_str(), msg.size());
    usleep(10000);

    //WRITE SLEEP COMMAND TO DEVICE FOR 0.5 SECONDS
    std::cout << "WRITING SLEEP COMMAND" << std::endl;
    msg="sys sleep 5000\r\n";//
    write(usb_port, msg.c_str(), msg.size());
    usleep(100000);

    //ATTEMPT TO SEND BREAK COMMAND
    ioctl(usb_port, TCSBRK, 0);
    usleep(500000);

    //RESET SERIAL BAUD RATE
    cfsetispeed(&tty, B115200);
    cfsetospeed(&tty, B115200);

    //SET DEVICE TO AUTO-BAUD RATE DETECTION
    std::cout << "SENDING 0x55" << std::endl;
    msg="0x55";
    write(usb_port, msg.c_str(), msg.size());
    usleep(2000000);

    //FLASH UNIT LED LIGHTS TO CONFIRM FINAL CONNECTION AT NEW BAUD RATE
    std::cout << "BLINKING LIGHTS" << std::endl;
    msg="sys set pindig GPIO11 1\r\n";
    write(usb_port, msg.c_str(), msg.size());
    usleep(1000000);
    msg="sys set pindig GPIO11 0\r\n";
    write(usb_port, msg.c_str(), msg.size());

    return usb_port;
}
```

Comment: pull the data line to the same voltage as a start bit for the period of a character time, maybe longer  .... at 57600 baud, that would be 200 microseconds or more

Comment: @jsotola , what do you mean by that code-wise?  So what goes in place of ioctl(usb_port, TCSBRK, 0);?

Comment: i have not looked at the code ... I'm only saying what a break is in serial communication ... it is possible that the LoRa device actually has a break character sequence, like old modems have ... for a modem, the break is `+++` ... could not hurt to try that

Comment: Yes, there is a separate reference to pulling the UART_RX pin low, which I think is what you're talking about.  However that pin isn't available to pull low in the firmware...which is odd.  The pins that are available according to the documrenation are

GPIO0-GPIO13, UART_CTS, UART_RTS, TEST0, TEST1

Comment: `Break` is a condition, and not a character.  It is a transmit capability of the UART, and accessible by serial terminal **ioctl()** and POSIX function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that may be searching for this solution down the road, here's the way I accomplished the task of setting the LoRa device into auto baud mode and opening the port at the new baud rate:

```
    int openPort(void) {
        struct termios tty;
        memset(&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
        //OPEN PORT WITH DEFAULT BAUD RATE 57600
        if ((usb_port = open(radiodevice, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC))>=0) {// | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC
            std::cout << "DEVICE OPENED: " << radiodevice << " handle number: " << usb_port << std::endl;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "unable to open serial radiodevice");
            return -1;
        }
        if(tcgetattr(usb_port, &tty) != 0) {
            printf("Error %i \n", errno);
        }
        cfsetispeed(&tty, B57600);
        cfsetospeed(&tty, B57600);
        tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;            // Make 8n1
        tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
        tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
        tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;
        tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;           // no flow control
        tty.c_cc[VMIN]   =  0;                  // read doesn't block
        tty.c_cc[VTIME]  =  5;                  // 0.5 seconds read timeout
        tty.c_iflag &= ~ISTRIP;
        tty.c_iflag &= ~INLCR;
        tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNCR;
        tty.c_iflag &= ~ICRNL;
        tty.c_oflag &= OPOST;
        tty.c_lflag &= ICANON;
        tcflush(usb_port,TCIOFLUSH);
        //usleep(10000);
        if (tcsetattr(usb_port, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
            printf("Error %i\n", errno);
        }

        //FLASH UNIT LED LIGHTS TO CONFIRM INITIAL CONNECTION
        std::string msg="sys set pindig GPIO11 1\r\n";
        write(usb_port, msg.c_str(), msg.size());
        usleep(1000000);
        msg="sys set pindig GPIO11 0\r\n";
        write(usb_port, msg.c_str(), msg.size());
        usleep(10000);

        //WRITE SLEEP COMMAND TO DEVICE FOR 0.5 SECONDS
        std::cout << "WRITING SLEEP COMMAND" << std::endl;
        msg="sys sleep 5000\r\n";
        write(usb_port, msg.c_str(), msg.size());
        usleep(100000);

        close(usb_port);

        //OPEN PORT AT NEW BAUD RATE
        if ((usb_port = open(radiodevice, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC))>=0) {// | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC
            std::cout << "DEVICE OPENED: " << radiodevice << " handle number: " << usb_port << std::endl;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "unable to open serial radiodevice");
            return -1;
        }
        if(tcgetattr(usb_port, &tty) != 0) {
            printf("Error %i \n", errno);
        }

        //RESET SERIAL BAUD RATE
        cfsetispeed(&tty, B230400);<---SET NEW BAUD RATE VALUE
        cfsetospeed(&tty, B230400);<---SET NEW BAUD RATE VALUE
        tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;            // Make 8n1
        tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
        tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
        tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;
        tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;           // no flow control
        tty.c_cc[VMIN]   =  0;                  // read doesn't block
        tty.c_cc[VTIME]  =  5;                  // 0.5 seconds read timeout
        tty.c_iflag &= ~ISTRIP;
        tty.c_iflag &= ~INLCR;
        tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNCR;
        tty.c_iflag &= ~ICRNL;
        tty.c_oflag &= OPOST;
        tty.c_lflag &= ICANON;
        tcflush(usb_port,TCIOFLUSH);
        usleep(10000);
        if (tcsetattr(usb_port, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
            printf("Error %i\n", errno);
        }

        //SEND BREAK COMMAND
        std::cout << "SENDING BREAK COMMAND" << std::endl;
        tcsendbreak(usb_port, 0);
        usleep(10000);

        //SET DEVICE TO AUTO-BAUD RATE DETECTION
        msg = "U";//CORRESPONDS TO DOCUMENTED CHARACTER 0x55
        write(usb_port, msg.c_str(), msg.size());

        //FLASH UNIT LED LIGHTS TO CONFIRM FINAL CONNECTION AT NEW BAUD RATE
        std::cout << "BLINKING LIGHTS" << std::endl;
        msg="sys set pindig GPIO11 1\r\n";
        write(usb_port, msg.c_str(), msg.size());
        usleep(1000000);
        msg="sys set pindig GPIO11 0\r\n";
        write(usb_port, msg.c_str(), msg.size());

        return usb_port;
    }
```

Comment: Your termios  settings are nonsensical.  Are `tty.c_oflag &= OPOST` and `tty.c_lflag &= ICANON;` really what you want?  That neither sets nor clears canonical modes; that only preserves whatever modes that already exist.  VMIN and VTIME values only have meaning in (input) noncanonical mode.  What modes are you using, or rather intend to use?

Comment: @sawdust  To be honest with you, I have no idea.  It works, but I'm sure it could be improved on greatly.  Are you recommending removing the ICANON flag completely?